# How to pass mongodb in-built function as paramater in insert query using python

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

I have a plan to create an index and delete it automatically. So according to the docs, it suggests ensureIndex function with createdAt parameter to do automatically. It works fine if I give the query directly in the mongo shell.

Now coming to the doubt, I have a list of entries with fields that are to be inserted in the specified collection using python. How should I give createdAt parameter which has a value new Date() which is a built-in in mongo so how to insert it?

```
In mongo shell:

db.test1.insert({ "createdAt": new Date(),    "logEvent": 2,    "logMessage": "Success!"})
```

Using python :

```
import pymongo
myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
mydb = myclient["sm"]
mycol = mydb["test1"]
d={}
d['logEvent']=2
d['logMessage']="Success!!"
d['createdAt']=new Date()
mycol.insert(d)
```

If i tried ,db.test1.find() displayed createAt as ISO date format

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5dca4d3a4845f6fcdd9bec84"), "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-11-12T06:12:10.942Z"), "logEvent" : 2, "logMessage" : "Success!" }
```

How to insert new Date()  using pymongo?

Answer (score 1):

When you're in the Mongo Shell, you have a complete Javascript environment at your disposal, in which `new Date` is a valid expression. It is not in Python.

What you want is to pass a date type object with the current time from Python to Mongo. The `pymongo` driver understands how to translate a Python `datetime` object into a Mongo `ISODate` type. So just give it that:

```
from datetime import datetime

d['createdAt'] = datetime.now()
```

Comment: It's not working. if i use direct insert the field is "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-11-12T09:34:49.102Z" , if i use insert through python the field is "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-11-12T15:04:53.435Z"

Comment: Then you may have to set your timezones correctly on your `datetime` object and/or ensure `pymongo` is timezone aware: https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html?highlight=tz_aware

Answer (score 0):

Mongodb uses the UTC timezone. So we need to pass UTC timezone formatted date object

```
    import pymongo
    from datetime import datetime
    myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
    mydb = myclient["sm"]
    mycol = mydb["test1"]
    d={}
    d['logEvent']=2
    d['logMessage']="Success!!"
    d['createdAt']=datetime.utcnow()
    mycol.insert(d)
```

Now it works and deletes the record automatically !!!